# How to solve exponential expressions?

Tags: exponentiation

There are some questions that I have.

Question 1)
 $$ (x^2/5)^3 = 2^6/5^y$$ 
To find the $y$ I used the same base

$$ 1/5^3 = 1/5y$$
Teacher told that the exponent will be the same if equaled,
so $ y = 3$. What my question is how would I find $x$?? Because I can't find the same base.

Question 2)

$$ (5 \cdot 6 )^2 = 5^x6^y$$
They don't have the same base, how would I solve them?

Comment: What do you mean "solve"

Comment: I need to be able to solve for x exponent on the first problem and on second even a few hint would help

Comment: You want so solve $y$ so like $y=....$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT (answer to the first question, the 2th you'll find out):

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{5}\right)^3=\frac{2^6}{5^y} \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$\frac{x^6}{125}=\frac{64}{5^y} \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$8000=x^6 \cdot 5^y \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$8000=x^6 \cdot 5^y \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$x^6 \cdot 5^y = 8000 \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$ 5^y = \frac{8000}{x^6} \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$ y = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{8000}{x^6}\right)}{\ln(5)}+\frac{2i\pi n}{\ln(5)}$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks for answering but i don't think this was the way i was taught..but is their a simple way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure
$$
\left(\frac{x^2}{5}\right)^3 = \frac{x^6}{5^3} = \frac{2^6}{5^y}
$$
so the simplest solution is $y=3$ and $x=2$.
similarly for the second equation.
$$
(5\cdot 6)^2 = 5^2\cdot 6^2 = 5^x6^y
$$
implies $x=2$ and $y=2$.

But your question is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Yes my question was how did you find x in the first problem?

Comment: like how did you get x = 2 in the first problem

Answer (score 1):

i would write $$\left(\frac{x^2}{5}\right)^3=\frac{2^6}{5^y}$$ is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^6=5^{3-y}$$
for 2) we can write $$5^2\cdot 6^2=5^x\cdot 6^y$$ and then $$5^{2-x}=6^{y-2}$$ and we can solve this for one variable.

Comment: I think the intention was to go from $5^2\cdot 6^2 = 5^x\cdot 6^y$ to $x=2,y=2$.  For example, we may want to solve for *integer values*.